# Back button url depending of previous page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a single post page on wordpress which can be accessible from two archive page.
I put a back button on this single post page and I would like to change the url of the back button depending of the previous page. Also I would like to change the url to one of the two archive if the single post is open in a new window.

Any idea is welcome.

Thank you

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

**HTML:**

`<a href="page.php?button=back">`




**PHP:**

```
<?php
    if($_GET['button'] == "back"){
         header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
It works almost, I just have a problem with the English language when comes from the regular archive page, it always return the French page. Here my code :

```
<div class="right-nav">
         <?php $id = icl_object_id($post->ID, 'page', 
false,ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);   


 // if comes from English client page   



if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 
"http://tmp.thomasdesnoyers.com/en/client/"):?>
     <a href="/en/client/">
            <input class="back-button"></input>
            </a>
 <?php

 // if comes from French client page      


elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 
"http://tmp.thomasdesnoyers.com/client/"):?>
     <a href="/client/">
            <input class="back-button"></input>
            </a>
 <?php

 // if comes from English regular archive page  


elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 
"http://tmp.thomasdesnoyers.com/en/"):?>
     <a href="/en/#post-<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <input class="back-button"></input>
            </a>
 <?php 

 // Else 


else:?>
    <a href="/#post-<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <input class="back-button"></input>
            </a>
<?php endif; ?> 





        </div>
```